# SOAP JAVA WSDL - Add a value in the request header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with a request to a **SOAP** service, I generated the client (**SWDL**) with **JAVA** and at the moment of making the request it returns an error message: "***org.apache.axis.AxisFault: THE SERVICE REQUIRES API KEY***" .

How can I add a token to the header in the following code?

```
ServiceImplSynchronization service = new ServiceSynchronizationLocator();
ServiceSynchronization ws = new ServiceSynchronizationSoapBindingStub(new URL(service.getServiceFacturacionSynchronizationPortAddress()), service);
ws.verifyCommunication();
```

**Result:**

```
org.apache.axis.AxisFault: THE SERVICE REQUIRES API KEY"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by overwriting the method in my service locator.

```
@Override
public Call createCall() throws ServiceException {
_call = new org.apache.axis.client.Call(this) {

    @Override
    public void setRequestMessage(Message msg) {
        super.setRequestMessage(msg);

        MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = msg.getMimeHeaders();
        mimeHeaders.addHeader("headerName", Value);


    }

};

return _call;
}
```